# Typescript create observable collection for mocking

Tags: typescript, observablecollection

For mocking purposes I need to create a hard coded Observable collection that looks like the following

Observable

I tried the following

```
IEnumerable<int> e = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.toObservable();
```

However I get error messages "Cannot find name IEnumerable" and Cannot find name List.

Comment: really typescript? No `IEnumerable` and `List` in TypeScript by default.

Comment: how do I get these two classes?

Comment: nowise. Typescript compiles into JavaScript. JavaScript has no IEnumerable and List. IEnumerable is just array and you can observate in JavaScript. Without observation your code cyn be converted to `var e: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want C# you would do this: 
List blah = new List { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
ObservableCollection observable = new ObservableCollection(blah);

For a Typescript you could try:

let t = Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5]);